# Granted user_birthday permission on ios facebook sdk

Tags: ios, permissions, facebook-sdk-4.0

I had granted permission on user_birthday, but I can not get the user bithday. The result[@"birthday"] return result is null, Why?

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login
     logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile", @"user_birthday"]
     fromViewController:self
     handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
         if (error) {
             NSLog(@"Process error");
         } else if (result.isCancelled) {
             NSLog(@"Cancelled");
         } else {
             NSLog(@"Logged in");
             NSLog(@"result==%@", result.grantedPermissions);
         }
     }];

[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:
              @{@"fields": @"birthday, name, id, age_range"}]
             startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

      NSString *birthdaytmp = result[@"birthday"];

      NSLog(@"%@", birthdaytmp);

}];
```

Comment: Is this code written back to back(I mean in same method?)

Comment: Is different method to call

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get you